# If i uncomment the print() function in the for loop, the 'groups' list is getting populated with empty lists instead of results

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, python-itertools

```
import itertools

data1 =[100,80,80,80,80,80,90,90,85,85,85]
keys = []
groups = []
sorted_data1 = sorted(data1)

for k,g in itertools.groupby(sorted_data1):
    #print('key: ',k,' group: ',list(g))
    keys.append(k)
    groups.append(list(g))

print('keys: ', keys)
print('Groups: ', groups)
```

RESULT OF ABOVE CODE:

```
keys:  [80, 85, 90, 100]
Groups:  [[80, 80, 80, 80, 80], [85, 85, 85], [90, 90], [100]]

RESULT I GET WHEN 'print()' IS UNCOMMENTED:
key:  80  group:  [80, 80, 80, 80, 80]
key:  85  group:  [85, 85, 85]
key:  90  group:  [90, 90]
key:  100  group:  [100]
keys:  [80, 85, 90, 100]
Groups:  [[], [], [], []]
```

Un-commenting print() in for-loop is giving 'groups' as list of empty lists. Please look into it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the loop

```
for k,g in itertools.groupby(sorted_data1):
```

`g` is itself an iterator, it's not a collection like a list.

When you call

```
print('key: ',k,' group: ',list(g))
```

inside the loop, the `list(g)` inside the print already goes through the entire iterator `g` to create the list. So, when you call

```
groups.append(list(g))
```

afterwards, `g` is already "empty" in some sense (more precisely: it is pointing to the end of the iterator), so there's nothing left to put in the list anymore

---

Like DDGG suggested, you can store the results of iterating through `g` once in a more permanent collection (like a `list`) first. Then you can re-use that list multiple times

Comment: Can u suggest an solution so that i could use both print() and append() both at the same time?

Comment: Save the collection once in a more permanent manner (e.g. using list(g) once first and storing it)

Answer (score 4):

Just as Dennis said, you can change your code to this to solve the problem:

```
import itertools

data1 = [100, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 90, 90, 85, 85, 85]
keys = []
groups = []
sorted_data1 = sorted(data1)

for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted_data1):
    group = list(g)
    print('key: ', k, ' group: ', group)
    keys.append(k)
    groups.append(group)

print('keys: ', keys)
print('Groups: ', groups)
```